# Hacer un insert SQL en una tabla intermedia

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, foreach

Buenas haber si me podeis ayudar.

Tengo un formulario, para editar propiedades en la base de datos. En ese formulario tengo un multi-select, donde selecciono los servicios que tiene esa propiedad. Esos servicios salen de una tabla que se llama servicio. Ese multi select me muestra los servicios que ya tiene cuando se añadio esa propiedad gracias a una tabla intermedia, donde tiene dos columnas, una que hace referencia a la id vivienda que pertenece y otra a la id del servicio que tiene la propiedad. Entonces se van añadiendo filas por servicio y vivienda.

Pero el problema me lo encuentro a la hora de editar los servicios que contiene esa vivienda.

Este es el select multiple del formulario de edición:

```
<div class="controls">
   <select id="select2-2" class="form-control" name="servicios" multiple>
   <?php
    $vivienda = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT viS.vivienda_vivienda_id, viS.servicio_servicio_id, serv.servicio_id, serv.nombre
    FROM vivienda_servicio AS viS
    RIGHT JOIN  servicio AS serv ON viS.servicio_servicio_id = serv.servicio_id");

    foreach ($vivienda as $viv){
   ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $viv['servicio_id']; ?>' <?php  if(trim($viv['vivienda_vivienda_id'])==$res['vivienda_id']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>><?php echo $viv['nombre']; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>
  </div>
```

**Luego lo envio por AJAX a un archivo que se llama `act-vivienda-alquiler.php`**

Luego una vez recibo todo por POST elimino todos los servicios que tiene esa vivienda.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM vivienda_servicio WHERE vivienda_vivienda_id=".$id);
```

Y por ultimo recorro todos los servicios recibidos por POST y los intento insertar, pero no hace nada.

```
foreach ($servicios as $insertarServicios){
 $results = $mysqli->query("
 INSERT INTO vivienda_servicio (vivienda_vivienda_id, servicio_servicio_id ) VALUES ($id, $insertarServicios)");
}
```

Alguna sugerencia por favor

Comment: Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Como comentario aparte, te recomendaría utilizar `START TRANSACTION`, ejecutar el borrado e insertado y luego `COMMIT`. De esta manera te aseguras de que la base de datos se queda en el estado inicial o en el nuevo, no en uno intermedio.

Comment: Desconozco esas funciones, si me preguntas cual es el problema? pues que no hace nada de nada, solamente lo borra. Probe a poner esto name="servicios[]" y si que lo hace pero sin borrar, entonces no se que tengo que hacer @jotaelesalinas